# How to restrict the window of RCP app from resizing?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp, rcp

I want to restrict the window size of an RCP app from resizing.
So in `prewindowopen` of `ApplicationWorkbenchWindowAdvisor` class I tried

```
IWorkbenchWindowConfigurer configurer = getWindowConfigurer();
    configurer.setShellStyle(SWT.CLOSE | SWT.MIN | SWT.MODELESS | SWT.BORDER | SWT.TITLE);
```

But it does not seem to have any effect on the window. When I tried the same things in a dialog this seems to work. Any clue on this will really help.

Comment: Have you checked your advisor is called during application startup?

Comment: @basilevs Yes i checked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like Eclipse bug [432501](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=432501) which is saying the `setShellStyle` is being ignored in Eclipse 4. There is currently no fix for this.

Comment: any alternative to restrict shell from resizing .I donot want to add listener on shell

Comment: You might be able to edit the application.e4xmi and use 'styleOverride' (see http://blog.vogella.com/2014/03/17/using-eclipse-application-model-persisted-state-to-specify-the-swt-stylebits/)

Comment: I am using eclipse 3x on eclipse 4 Still i have not moved to E4 .

Comment: The e4xmi file is still used with 3.x on Eclipse 4 (called LegacyIDE.e4xmi in the org.eclipse.platform plugin).  I believe it is possible to modify this.